C# Remove namespace references and usage from XML data
I'm obtaining Swift MX messages and need to remove namespaces from them. In essence, they are two XML documents glued together. Most of the time they look like this:
<AppHdr> contents of the header </AppHdr><Document> contents of the document </Document>
This is easy to deal with as I put <root> and </root> around the whole thing to make XML (one root node only) and read it into an XmlDocument:
<root><AppHdr> ... </AppHdr><Document> ... </Document></root>
However, some of the messages have namespaces and the namespace is unknown at designtime. An example might be:
<ns2:AppHdr xmlns:ns2="some stuff"> contents of the header </ns2:AppHdr><ns3:Document xmlns:ns3="some other stuff"> contents of the document </ns3:Document>
Note that all of the XML tree under AppHdr quote the namespace tag of AppHdr and those under Document quote that of Document.
The namespace tags may vary. In this example they are ns2 and ns3, but I don't know what they will be in advance. Is there an easy way to strip these out?

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
Please edit your original question and provide the following:
(1) Well-formed XML file sample.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.

It could be easily done via XSLT.

Nearly every request about removing namespaces is due to misunderstanding their purpose and how to deal with them.  Be aware that you're veering off the recommended path by removing namespaces and likely creating trouble for yourself and/or others working with the resulting XML document.

@kjhughes - I hear your warning. Am wondering what you might perceive to be a problem in the example above. I'm not sure how having two different namespaces (and only sometimes) adds to the meaning of the documents.

It's not a matter of what I perceive; it's a matter of the fact that XML components (elements and attributes) in an XML namespace intentionally have different names than those in no namespace.  Name spacing serves several purposes, including avoiding name collisions and establishing authority for defining syntax/semantics.  Most requests to remove them are due to ignorance of their purpose and/or of the mechanics of working with them, not because it's the best design decision overall.

A minimal reproducible example is not provided. Here is a generic XSLT based solution that will work with any well-formed XML file.
Input XML
<root>
   <ns2:AppHdr xmlns:ns2="some stuff">*contents of the header*</ns2:AppHdr>
   <ns3:Document xmlns:ns3="some other stuff">*contents of the document*</ns3:Document>
</root>

XSLT
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <!-- template to copy elements -->
   <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- template to copy attributes -->
   <xsl:template match="@*">
      <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- template to copy the rest of the nodes -->
   <xsl:template match="comment() | text() | processing-instruction()">
      <xsl:copy/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Output XML
<root>
  <AppHdr>*contents of the header*</AppHdr>
  <Document>*contents of the document*</Document>
</root>

c#
void Main()
{
   const string SOURCEXMLFILE = @"e:\Temp\input.xml";
   const string XSLTFILE = @"e:\Temp\process.xslt";
   const string OUTPUTXMLFILE = @"e:\temp\output.xml";

   try
   {
      XsltArgumentList xslArg = new XsltArgumentList();

      using (XmlReader src = XmlReader.Create(SOURCEXMLFILE))
      {
         XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
         xslt.Load(XSLTFILE, new XsltSettings(true, true), new XmlUrlResolver());

         XmlWriterSettings settings = xslt.OutputSettings.Clone();
         settings.IndentChars = "\t";
         // to remove BOM
         settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);

         using (XmlWriter result = XmlWriter.Create(OUTPUTXMLFILE, settings))
         {
            xslt.Transform(src, xslArg, result, new XmlUrlResolver());
            result.Close();
         }
      }
      Console.WriteLine("File '{0}' has been generated.", OUTPUTXMLFILE);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }
}


Hi @Yitzhak, thank you for your reply. I can't easily give a minimal working example as it means pasting in sensitive financial data, which I'm obviously not allowed to. I'm not sure that the namespace strings, or structure of Swift messages are public domain, hence the minimal nature of the question. Thank you for your clear and comprehensive answer. I will use this. Much appreciated.
